# Handling event outside the iframe for the element within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog

My page structure is like

I have a `html` page which consist of a `jQuery` Dialog.
Within the `jQuery` Dialog a screen opens within `iFrame`.

Now the problem I am facing is - I want to close `jQuery` Dialog by clicking a button within `iFrame`. (For e.g. If my iFrame source is Google.com, then on click of search button my dialog box should close)

So, Can I write close call handling click event of search button in `$(document).ready(function()` of my html page?

**Note** :- iframe source is not accessible.

If no, then what are the other possible option to do it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `iFrame` source is on a different domain than you cannot do this.

**Options**

- Use the Dialog's built in close functionality
- If the position of your item that you want to trigger the close is fixed, you can overlay a div covering. Fire the close event on the clicking of the div. http://jsfiddle.net/YvbPB/

Comment: Thanks, a good suggestion, yet I want something different, as if I overlap the position of the search button may vary and look of the page would be disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) my friend.

Comment: Thanks to search for me, but it didnt server my purpose.